# Validate the logged in user by JWT

Tags: angular, .net-core, jwt

I'm using JWT authentication with ASP.NET Core Web API. The process I follow.

1. Generate the token on server side and send it to the client.
2. The client sends back the token on the header with each request.\
3. Server validates the token and responds with the requested information.

I store the token in the localstorage of the client. My problem is,

1. Logged in as two separate users from two different browsers (Logged in by using an username and password just as any normal login).
2. Swap the token stored in the localstorage of the two users.

The server still validates the tokens as valid even though the requests are from different users.

Simply, anyone can hack into the system by just modifying the localstorage with a valid token.

How do I resolve this security loophole?

Answer (score 3):

One of the common ways of preventing is to have the IP the source (from where he logged in) as a part of the signed JWT. Due to this security concern, JWT is also generally stored using secure mechanisms. You can look into the best ways to store your JWT based on the client and the framework you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You are right but This is how JWT works.

Possible solutions :
Use Http secure cookies and read JWT from cookies instead of using and storing token from localsotage

Ping me if you have any query on that

Comment: while this sounds secure for web apps, I am not sure how well this would work with mobile and on the statelessness.

Comment: cookies do exist in mobile apps and server can read it easily on api calls. Statlessness concept halts when you start saving JWT because of some business logic.

BTW you can detect target device and choose appropriate strategy to store JWT.
leme know if you need further clarification on that or have questions. :)
and kindly mention which tech. you are using for mobile apps

Comment: I was mainly making sure the idea works for all possible clients/techs since one of the aims of APIs is to be flexible to any kind of clients in future

Comment: yes don't worry It will work fine. Otherwise stackoverflow is here.

kindly accept the ans if you got solution otherwise ur questions are welcome :)

Comment: it's not my question. I can't accept. you need to wait for the OP.

Comment: sure no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

JWT are only one layer of a secure system. They exist to securely identify an authenticated user and possibly include additional authorization data about the user (roles, claims, etc.) in a way where tampering may be *possible*, but it can also be easily detected.

So, you are right, additional measures are required to build a secure system, such as:

1. Only send tokens over secure channels to prevent MITM attacks.
2. Give tokens short lifetimes so that possible attack and exploit windows are narrow.
3. Ensure the user is logged out (and the token invalidated) after x minutes of inactivity by the user.

Answer (score -1):

You're right. If someone has the token, they can request to the back-end side without any problems. It means that they can do too much with a token that they have stolen. That's why tokens often have expirations and refresh tokens.

In my opinion, I think you should set a short expiration time for a token and use the mechanism of the refresh token

Comment: Hi Thank you for the comment. What happens if the person who stoles the token keep using it? then he will get the refreshed tokens too right? On the other hand, the genuine user is logged out because he was using the expired token?

Comment: once you figure out it is being misused, the token has to be misused. the real user needs to be asked to log in again (don't use a compromised token for anyone) so he gets a new JWT

Comment: You can't minimize the expiration time to minimize security risks

Comment: I didn't said that short-lived access token may minimize security risk :)  I mean that we should use a combination of access tokens and refresh tokens for maximum security and flexibility.